# Android - Erasing view above fragment introduces delay in touch event

Tags: android, android-fragments

**The context**

I'm developing an application where the user can reveal a content (mapfragment) through erasing with its fingers the view in front.

I've created a customView (similar to google fingerpaint - erasing sample) handling the drawing and I add this view in front of my content.
I've added a function to log the time between two ontouchevent moves.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
  mTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-mTime;
  mTimeList.add(mTime);
  mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  [...]
  path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
  invalidate();
  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  int listSize = mTimeList.size();
  long value =0;
  for (Long time : mTimeList) {
  value = value+time;
  }
  int finalvalue = (int) ((value/listSize));
  Log.i("MotionEvent", "Average time : "+Long.toString(finalvalue));
break;
```

**My problem**

- When I create my activity and set layout to my custom view, it works very well. There is only my customView, and the time between two moves is around **17ms**.

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(new MyView(this));
  ```
- When I create my activity and add my custom view to an empty mainlayout (relativelayout), the time between two moves is almost the same.

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mapfullscreen_hotcold);
  RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mapfullscreen_relativeLayout);
  MyView view = new MyView(this);
  mainLayout.addView(view);
  ```
- When I create my activity and add my custom view to a mainlayout (relativelayout) which includes a mapfragment, the time between two moves is around **47ms**.

  ```
  ---ACTIVITY---
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mapfullscreen_hotcold);
  RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mapfullscreen_relativeLayout);
  MyView view = new MyView(this);
  mainLayout.addView(view);

  ---XML---
  <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mapfullscreen_relativeLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <fragment
  android:id="@+id/mapfullscree_mapLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

What can I do to make it faster?

When I touch the view, the content below should not impact my view-motionevent, right?

EDIT:
And when I add my custom view to a mainlayout (relativelayout) which includes an imageView populated with mapsStaticAPI, the time between two moves is around 17ms/19ms.

What are the solutions to keep a googleMapsFragment with a short delay between two moves?